# Web Scraping yelp review rating Python

Tags: python, web-scraping

```
rating=[] 

for i in range(0,10):
    
    url = "https://www.yelp.com/biz/snow-show-flushing?osq=ice%20cream%20shop&start="+str(10*i)

    ourUrl = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    
    
    soup = BeautifulSoup(ourUrl,'html.parser')
    for r in soup.find_all('span',{'class':"display--inline__373c0__1gaV4 border-color--default__373c0__1yxBb"})[1:]:  
        per_rating = r.div.get('aria-label')
        rating.append(per_rating)
```

Try to get ratings for each page. Should have only 58 ratings in total, but it includes the rating from the "you might also consider".

How to fix it.

Comment: My guess is that that portion of the page is being populated with JavaScript, which cannot be accessed with urllib's urlopen function. Have you considered trying a package like Selenium to obtain the HTML, then parse it with BeautifulSoup (or equivalent)? This link may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8049520/web-scraping-javascript-page-with-python

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution would be to retrieve the total number of Reviews from yelp using BeautifulSoup. You can then trim your "rating"-list by the number of reviews.

```
# find the total number of reviews:
regex_count = re.compile('.*css-foyide.*')
Review_count = soup.find_all("p", {"class": regex_count})
Review_count = Review_count[0].text
Review_count = int(Review_count.split()[0]) # total number of reviews
```